# Do these java classes have correct structures to map from a JSON file?

Tags: java, json, serialization, collections, getter-setter

I'm parsing a `JSON` file into a java code from a particular URL. It looks easy. But, for some reasons the server respond with `null` for some *key-values* that I'll show below. I'm quite sure there something wrong over these structures (on the java sides).
Here is the json structure.

[image]

And here are the codes (the getters-setters have been provided I just don't show them to make it clear)

```
class JSON {

    List<Result> result;

}


class Results{
    String gender;
    Name name;
    Location location
}


class Name{
    String title;
    String first;
    String last;
}

class Location {
    String city;
    String state;
    String country;
    String postcode;

}
```

I'm not sure where exactly I missed it. Are those classes have correct structures relative to the JSON structure?

Comment: What are the null fields? It all seems correct from your image.

Comment: And do mention how you're parsing the `JSON`?

Comment: Note that `postcode` has a numeric type in the JSON .

Comment: Hi, the other key which is *Info* (class *Info*) has a same hierarchical position to the *Results* and It got mapped correctly, but not the *results*

Comment: @Mushif Ali Nawaz, It's actually the *result* variable that couldn't be parsed, eventhought the type was correct(i.e. Result). This is because the variable's getter method name should match the name after the prefix.I.e. I have *getResults()* so the variable must be *results*. I don't see any reasons why should I tell you what I want to do with the json. Because, my question is pretty simple, where does this go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to have `results` instead of `result` in JSON class

Comment: Edit : It's not the name of the type but the field really matters. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your Java Class and JSON response in object Location there is not Inner Object street.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe this one is missed. But it's just missing in my example.

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem,

The String postcode seems to be a number in the JSON above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is User defined class reference null
Try this one and create **HAS-A reference to Object**
Initialize the objects using constructor()

```
class JSON {
        List<Result> result;
        public JSON(){
           result = new ArrayList()
        }


    }


    class Results{
        String gender;
        Name name;
        Location location
        public Results(){
           Name = new Name();
           Location = new Location();
        }
    }


    class Name{
        String title;
        String first;
        String last;
    }

    class Location {
        String city;
        String state;
        String country;
        String postcode;

    }
```